# What is the AWS Attribute outputs and ImportValue in cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-fsx

i'm starting my AWS journey and today got a chance to Create `cloudformation` stack for creating a filesystem on the AWS, i was able to spun the filesystem, however I have few
doubts about some values and functions/attributes as those were given by someone in the team and he on long vacations so, asking here for help.

Below is `cloudfoemation Stack` which works Just fine.

**Cloudformaton Stack:**

```
---
Description: "Create FSxN filesystem"
Resources:
  MytestCluster:
    Type: "AWS::FSx::FileSystem"
    Properties:
      FileSystemType: "ONTAP"
      StorageCapacity: "1024"
      SubnetIds: ['subnet-0f349h6eee098b0pg']
      OntapConfiguration:
        DeploymentType: "SINGLE_AZ_1"
        PreferredSubnetId: "subnet-0f349h6eee098b0pg"
        ThroughputCapacity: "128"
        FsxAdminPassword: '{{resolve:secretsmanager:fsx_admin_password}}'
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - !ImportValue 'KPCL-FSxforONTAPsgID'
      Tags:
        - Key: "Backup"
          Value: "None"
  MytestSVM:
    Type: "AWS::FSx::StorageVirtualMachine"
    Metadata:
      cfn-lint:
        config:
          ignore_checks:
            - E3001
    Properties:
      FileSystemId: !Ref MytestCluster
      Name: svmdemo
      RootVolumeSecurityStyle: "UNIX"
      SvmAdminPassword: '{{resolve:secretsmanager:svm_admin_password}}'
      Tags:
        - Key: "Backup"
          Value: "None"
  fsxndemovolume:
    Type: "AWS::FSx::Volume"
    Metadata:
      cfn-lint:
        config:
          ignore_checks:
            - E3001
    Properties:
      Name: myTestVol001
      OntapConfiguration:
        JunctionPath: /myVolume001
        SizeInMegabytes: 1536000
        StorageEfficiencyEnabled: true
        StorageVirtualMachineId: !Ref MytestSVM
      VolumeType: "ONTAP"
      Tags:
        - Key: "Backup"
          Value: "None"
Outputs:
  FileSystemId:
    Value: !Ref "MytestCluster"
  SvmId:
    Value: !Ref "MytestSVM"
...
```

**I would like Understand:**

I have few doubts to myself to clear which i tried to understand from document but couldn't comprehend well, hence though taking expert suggestion..

**First one:** below  under `SecurityGroupIds` what does  `- !ImportValue` mean here.

```
  SecurityGroupIds:
    - !ImportValue 'KPCL-FSxforONTAPsgID'
```

**Second one:** What is `outputs` means here.

```
Outputs:
  FileSystemId:
    Value: !Ref "MytestCluster"
  SvmId:
    Value: !Ref "MytestSVM"
```

**Last one:** what is `ignore_checks:` and its value `- E3001` here.

```
      ignore_checks:
        - E3001
```

Please help me to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First one: below under SecurityGroupIds what does  - !ImportValue mean here.

The following:

```
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - !ImportValue 'KPCL-FSxforONTAPsgID'
```

means that in the current stack your are going to [import](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html) security group ID which was [exported](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-stack-exports.html) by some other stack.

This export/import functionality allows you to **decouple** and **reuse** your infrastructure. Instead of having everything in one stack, you can make one stack with network resources (its a common setup), such as security groups, subnets, VPCs, and other stacks that actual use those resources.

> Second one: What is outputs means here.

[Outputs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/outputs-section-structure.html) allow you to return values from your stacks. You can think of them as a type of return values from functions in common programming languages.

Output values have lots of use-cases. Examples are: they can be exported, and imported in other stacks. They can also be queried programmatically, in case your stacks are part of some CI/CD pipelines or other application. They can be used as input parameters to other stacks, again as port of some CI/CD pipeline. This is alternative to export/import functionality.

> Last one: what is ignore_checks: and its value - E3001 here.

This is some extra code not related to CloudFormation itself. It is actually a hint to Visual Studio Code 
[cfn-lint-visual-studio-code](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-lint-visual-studio-code) editor to ignore some auto checks it does.

Comment: Marcin, Thanks for detailed explanation  +1, i'll go through it ., I believe we can remove that CFN lint part from teh CFN as that's not play any role here.

Comment: @microncloud yes, you can remove entier `Metadata` block.

Comment: @microncloud Did you try without `Metadata`?

Comment: not really but overall it makes me enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Outputs in stack creates exports in cloudformation which can be listed in AWS Console, `!Import` directive is used to reference to export from another stack.

`cfn-lint` section in metadata is used to silent errors in [CloudFormation Linter tool](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-lint) and has no impact to the resource itself.

Comment: There is no such thing as `!Import`.

Comment: @Marcin, Its `!ImportValue`

Comment: @Marcin, Would you mind explaining please, we'll also learn something from you.

Comment: @Lasek, thanks for the answer +1 for the, will mark that answer in another few mins.